# Strict subsets in vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

Find proper subsets $S_1,S_2,S_3 \neq \{(0,0)\}$ in vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$ so that:
$$S_1 + S_2 \subsetneq S_1$$
$$S_2 \subsetneq S_2+S_2$$
$$S_3+S_3=S_3$$

I wrote out the addition definitions:
$$S_1+S_2 = \{s_1+s_2\mid s_1\in S_1,\ s_2\in S_2\}\subsetneq S_1$$
$$S_2+S_2=\{ s_{21}+s_{22} \mid s_{21},s_{22} \in S_2 \}\supsetneq S_2$$
$$S_3+S_3 = \{ s_{31}+s_{32} \mid s_{31},s_{32} \in S_3 \}=S_3$$
How should I proceed from this?

Comment: This problem doesn't have much to do with vector spaces, as $S_2$ cannot be a subspace (since then $S_2=S_2+S_2$).

Comment: You could start by trying experimenting with some simple sets, to get a feel of what the operation does. For example what does $S+S$ look like for $S=(0,\infty)\times\{0\}$? What about $S=(1,\infty)\times\{0\}$? Or $S=(-1,1)\times\{0\}$? You can also have a look at sums of some pairs of sets.